# Modelica - change only one parameter of a complexe type connector

Tags: connector, modelica

having a complex connector, when propagating it, I want to modify only one variable of the set of variables, without having to explicitely write all the equality equations for the other variables.

Ideal would be a connect statement and an overwriting of just that one specific variable.

```
    class FluidClass
        String name(start="name")"name";
        Real fl(start=1000)"flow [l/h]";
        Real p(start=1)"pressure [bar]";
        Real T(start=25)"temperature [degC]";
        Real DS(start=80)"dry substance [%]";
        Real rho(start=100)"viscosity [mPas]";
    end FluidClass;

    connector fl "flow"
        extends FluidClass;
    end fl;

        model setParam "set parameter"
        fl fli annotation(Placement(
            transformation(extent={{-5,-5},{5,5}}),
            iconTransformation(extent={{-105,-5},{-95,5}})));
        fl flo "flow output" annotation(Placement(
            transformation(extent={{-50,0},{-40,10}}),
            iconTransformation(extent={{95,-5},{105,5}})));
        input Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput u "set value";
        parameter EnumType1 var "variable to change";
        type EnumType1 = enumeration( 
            fl "Flow rate", 
            p "Pressure", 
            T "Temperature", 
            DS "Dry substance", 
            rho "Viscosity");
        equation
            // enter your equations here
            if var ==1 then //flow
            flo.name=fli.name;
            flo.fl=u;
            flo.p=fli.p;
            flo.T=fli.T;
            flo.DS=fli.DS;
            flo.rho=fli.rho;
            end if;

            if var ==2 then //pressure
            flo.name=fli.name;
            flo.fl=fli.fl;
            flo.p=u;
            flo.T=fli.T;
            flo.DS=fli.DS;
            flo.rho=fli.rho;
            end if;

            if var ==3 then //temperature
            flo.name=fli.name;
            flo.fl=fli.fl;
            flo.p=fli.p;
            flo.T=u;
            flo.DS=fli.DS;
            flo.rho=fli.rho;
            end if;

            if var ==4 then //DS
            flo.name=fli.name;
            flo.fl=fli.fl;
            flo.p=fli.p;
            flo.T=fli.T;
            flo.DS=u;
            flo.rho=fli.rho;
            end if;

            if var ==5 then //viscosity
            flo.name=fli.name;
            flo.fl=fli.fl;
            flo.p=fli.p;
            flo.T=fli.T;
            flo.DS=fli.DS;
            flo.rho=u;
            end if;
    end setParam;
```

I would highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not a very Modelica-ish way to build such models.  There seem to be several things going on in this model.  First, it appears that you are trying to specify the type of fluid through this "name" parameter.  You are also propagating information through these connectors but you are propagating different types of information.  Things like pressure, temperature and mass fractions (p, T, DS) should really be across variables, things like fluid flow (fl) should be through variables and density (rho) should be a fluid property.

There are facilities in Modelica for handling all of these cases but you are not utilizing them in your example.  Furthermore, the approach you are using will not really scale very well because you don't have sufficient information in your flow path (you don't track energy being convected by the fluid nor differentiate how much of your flow is "dry" (dry air vs water vapor?).

You should really have a look at some fluid examples (for example, the Modelica.Fluid library or the examples in my book, "Introduction to Physical Modeling with Modelica") because once you take into account these design changes, your question will be moot (hence my non-answer).

I am sorry about the non-answer here, but I hope you find the information constructive enough to point you in the right direction.  If not, feel free to ask other questions or add comments and I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm glad YOU answered my answered my question, as I saw many of your contributions and read some of your works over the net.

Comment: Actually, I played a little bit around with the fluid bibliotheques, but were just overwhelmed and furthermore either did not understand their proper use, or did not get them running. 

What I am doing is trying to get my colleagues away from excel, with a tool which I found more appropriate with it's OO approach and the dynamic component, which allows for deeper inspection of our models.

Comment: I hope having found it with Modelica and in order to get a "smoother" intro in the subject, I tried to build up my "own" bibliotheque, without overloading it with too much accurate facts. Really to limit it in a first step to what we are doing in excel right now.

Unfortunately there is not as much help available as for "mainstream" software, so that the learning curve is much flatter than with other software tools.
However, again thank you very much and I'll try to follow your advice.

Comment: A good introduction to this topic is the following paper: https://modelica.org/events/Conference2003/papers/h40_Elmqvist_fluid.pdf